# Android battery usage keep awake explanation

Tags: android, power-management

In the Battery usage screen there is a time for "Keep awake". What does that mean exactly? Is there any documentation somewhere about those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This talk from Google IO on Coding for Battery life kind of clears it a little better:
http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=OUemfrKe65c

Comment: even though I still don't know where the exact numbers I see on that screen come from

Comment: This link doesn't work for me. Erdal can you update your answer to actually include information? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to show the amount of time that an app has asked the OS to stay in a waking state.

You can see the [options available to the developer in the PowerManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

For example, an app can request a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. As long as at least one app has requested a partial wake lock, the device will stay active (and consuming battery) even when the screen is off. From the docs:

> If the user presses the power button, then the screen will be turned
>   off but the CPU will be kept on until all partial wake locks have been
>   released.

I believe the `Keep awake` time is reporting for how long a given app had this flag set.

Examples on my phone right now,

- Google Chrome Beta has an extremely short `Keep awake` time, 5s. This looks very well behaved.
- Another app known to be a terrible battery hog has a `Keep awake` of nearly 2 hours, despite being actively used for only a few minutes. I would guess this app is not releasing its partial wake lock.

Answer (score -1):

It keeps the screen awake while charging. You can check this discussion.
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/team-d1-miui/103349-battery-settings-question-stay-awake.html
You may also note that this time that you talk about seems like the time which this phone uses this function.

Comment: that's not what I was asking about. It is not an action. It just tells you for how long the app "kept awake" the device. What I want to know is what did the app do? what kind of lock did it hold?

Comment: Exactly what I told you... It keeps the phone from going into a sleep mode kind of state

Comment: The question is about the "Keep awake" time which is displayed in Battery Settings against an individual app. It is not related to the "Stay awake" control mentioned in your post.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is to keep your screen from sleeping while you recharge your battery.

Here's a relevant topic: 
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/team-d1-miui/103349-battery-settings-question-stay-awake.html

Comment: The question is about the "Keep awake" time which is displayed. It is not related to the "Stay awake" control mentioned in your post.